# XUL dialog doesn't close after pressing "Close" button

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have a dialog in my addon which is opened when some deletion process is completed. I use for all such messages XUL dialog that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://myaddon/skin/Style.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://myaddon/locale/mydtd.dtd">

<dialog xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        class="dialog" ondialogcancel="return true;">
    <dialogheader id="dlgHdr"/>
    <vbox flex="1" id="content" pack="center">
    </vbox>
    <script
        type="application/x-javascript"
        src="chrome://myaddon/content/mainScript.js"
    />
    <script
        type="application/x-javascript"
        src="chrome://myaddon/content/dialogInit.js"
    />
    <tfs_string id="new-profile-success" value="&newProfileSuccess.Text;"
                style="overflow: hidden" />
    <tfs_string id="delete-profile-success" value="&deleteProfileSuccess.Text;"
                style="overflow: hidden" />
</dialog>
```

It has cancel button, *ondialogcancel* handler returns true. But it doesn't close immediately after pressing button. I have to drag this dialog a little to make it disappear. Moreover, this problem only happens when I restart browser after reinstalling addon. After one more  restart dialog is closed immediately after i press Cancel. I use this dialog for some other messages, and they don't have such a problem.

If I close window and open it again with Chromebug debugger instead of restarting using popup, I can't reproduce this bug. But if I lauch another FF version and then first version again (with debugger), I manage to reproduce it. But when I use step-by-step execution on dialogcancel handler, Chromebug's interface becomes unresponsive (except script content area) and dialog doesn't close after I see in debugger that window.close() is executed, so I have to drag dialog window around a little again to make it disappear.
What should I do?

Comment: What if you remove these scripts? The dialog as you have it here should work correctly (and definitely not have any dependencies on when the extension was installed), I suspect that the issue is elsewhere - likely in `mainScript.js` or `dialogInit.js`.

Comment: The thing is other dialog uses don't have any problems (e.g. new profile success initializer has different parameter for message string that's all). And this deletion process completion dialog works fine after I restart browser again (so it's two restarts after updating addon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the reason. Problem was indeed caused by dialogInit.js script.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () { myext.simpleDialogInitialize(); }, false);
window.addEventListener("MozAfterPaint", function () { window.sizeToContent(); }, false);
window.addEventListener('unload', function () { myext.simpleDialogFinalize(); }, false);
```

It contains even handlers for 'load' and 'unload' events. First one calls initializer specified in a method that opens this window. But there was one more handler for 'MozAfterPaint' event that called window.sizeToContent, so that infinite loop was triggered, I guess. Extension wasn't created from scratch so I didn't notice this mistake for some time. I moved resizing to the 'load' event handler after calling that initializer, works fine.